# Python DB2 eliminate (' ',) on every result

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, db2

I'm extracting data from a DB2 database in Python, this is currently my code:

```
cur = conn_db2.cursor()
res = []
sql = "SELECT subject FROM LIB.SCHOOL"
cur.execute(sql)
for loop in cur:
    res.append(loop)
```

The data is right, but it appears like this when I show the list:

```
(' MATH ',)
(' SPANISH ',)
(' SCIENCE ',)
```

I just wanna keep the subject names.

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't expect it would be that easy!

Answer (score 0):

`loop` is a tuple of all the columns being selected. Use indexing to get just the first column.

Use `strip()` to remove surrounding whitespace (although I wonder why you put the spaces into the database in the first place).

```
res = [loop[0].strip() for loop in cur]
```